# Getting null from flask request python

Tags: python, flask, null

I am writing a simple flask application where based on my query, I should get the required answer in the desired format.
The code is as below;

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import StringIO
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from flask import Flask, request, Response, abort, jsonify, send_from_directory,make_response
import io
from pandas import DataFrame
import urllib2, json
import requests
from flask import session
import sys  


reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding("ISO-8859-1")
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/api/conversation/", methods=['POST'])
def chatbot():
    df = pd.DataFrame(json.load(urllib2.urlopen('http://192.168.21.245/sixthsensedata/server/Test_new.json')))
    question = request.form.get('question')
    store = []

    if question == 'What is the number of total observation of the dataset':
       store.append(df.shape)

    if question == 'What are the column names of the dataset':
       store.append(df.columns)
    return jsonify(store)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host = '192.168.21.11',port=5000)
```

It's running properly but getting null response. I would like to create ~30 more questions like this & store values in the `store` array. But values are not getting appended inside `store`, I think.

In jupyter notebook, though, I am getting proper response;

```
df = pd.DataFrame(json.load(urllib2.urlopen('http://192.168.21.245/sixthsensedata/server/Test_new.json')))
store = []
store.append(df.shape)
print store
[(521, 24)]
```

Why in flask, the values are not getting appended? I am testing my application in postman. Please guide where I am lacking.

Screenshot from postman[image]

Comment: add `print question` just before the `if` just to make sure that quesion is not empty and we will continue from there

Comment: I checked by giving the print command, it is receiving the question. I gave 'print 1' just before if, & 1 is printed in the terminal

Comment: you did not understand what i wanted from you - i want to see the value of the `question` variable

Comment: Yes got you now & you are right. 'print question' is returning 'None', though I don't know why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When not providing the data type for the Post method, request.form evaluates to

`ImmutableMultiDict([('{"question": "What is the number of total observation of the dataset"}', u'')])`

and `question = request.form.get('question')` ends up being none
You can explicitly use content type as json, or force load it.

```
@app.route('/api/conversation/', methods=['POST'])
def chatbot():
    question = request.get_json(force=True).get('question')
    store = []

    if question == 'What is the number of total observation of the dataset':
        store.append("shape")
    elif question == 'What are the column names of the dataset':
        store.append("columns")
    return jsonify(store)
```

Curl requests

```
$curl -X POST -d '{"question": "What is the number of total observation of the dataset"}' http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/conversation/
```

["shape"]

```
$curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST -d '{"question": "What is the number of total observation of the dataset"}' http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/conversation/
```

["shape"]

Comment: This worked but not in request.form; The postman screenshot I attached, was taking input from 'x-www-form-urlencoded', your modification throwing error over there. But when I tried the same in 'raw', it worked.

Comment: You can check for the content type in the flask, if input from 'x-www-form-urlencoded' is really needed then you should work with the

    ImmutableMultiDict([('question', u'What is the number of total observation of the dataset')])

Get the elements in this way `request.form.keys()[0]`

Comment: @HindolGanguly For better testing, it will be better to directly use a HTML input and know how the post data is being sent. If it is meant only to be a REST api, then it is better to specify content-type for better usability and less confusion